# Systemd: Python service can't be restarted after stop

Tags: systemd, python, raspbian, services, daemon

On Raspbian Jessie I'm writing a Python script automatically ran by systemd. As a SSCCE let's write a trivial Python script as a service:

```
cat >/home/pi/service.py <<EOF
from time import sleep
sleep(99999)
EOF
```

This is interruptible via SIGINT, so I setup the service like this and tell systemd SIGINT is the right way to close it:

```
cat >/lib/systemd/system/python-service.service <<EOF
[Unit]
Description=Python service

[Service]
Type=simple
TTYPath=/dev/tty1
StandardInput=tty
StandardOutput=tty
ExecStart=/usr/bin/nohup /usr/bin/python /home/pi/service.py
KillSignal=SIGINT
SuccessExitStatus=SIGINT

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

EOF
```

I then setup systemd to launch this service:

```
systemctl set-default multi-user.target
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl enable python-service.service
```

The service is properly setup, ran, and can be stopped, but can't be restarted unless we reboot:

```
# I first check that the service has been run at startup:
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ systemctl status python-service.service 
● python-service.service - Python service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/python-service.service; enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2017-01-09 01:56:47 UTC; 59s ago
 Main PID: 419 (python)
   CGroup: /system.slice/python-service.service
           └─419 /usr/bin/python /home/pi/service.py

# It runs fine, now I stop it
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo systemctl stop python-service.service 

# Let's start it again
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo systemctl start python-service.service 

# And consult the current status, I assume the parenthesis mean there is an issue
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ systemctl status python-service.service 
● python-service.service - Python service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/python-service.service; enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2017-01-09 01:59:54 UTC; 2s ago
 Main PID: 833 ((nohup))
   CGroup: /system.slice/python-service.service
           └─833 (nohup)

# And indeed no service.py is running
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ps ax|grep service
  839 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto service
```

Comment: My guess is the TTYPATH=/dev/tty1 setting. `systemd.exec(5)` mentions that the executed process will wait until it can be made the controling process of the terminal. At system boot, nothing is using /dev/tty1, but later on something uses it. Try changing the `Standard{Input,Output}` settings to `tty-fail` and try the whole thing again. If the service fails immediately, then that's it.

Comment: Mmmmh with `tty-fail` the service continues to start but no longer restarts, same as before. But with `tty-force` it works, it restarts well! Should I disabled getty on tty1 so that it's free?

Comment: Why are you even making this service use a TTY in the first place?

Comment: The service outputs debug information about its states on stdout, real time display when a monitor is connected is much meaningful than consulting the log offline. However that configuration here above with `tty-force` causes autologin on tty1 which I do not want, and also disables tty2 to tty4 very it's strange (tty>=5 work fine with a login prompt). Stopping the service and restarting it make the tty2 to 4 working again.